# What is wrong with this RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
§serverUrl§/image/?url=§externalMedia.data.image§
```

and I want to match only the string inside the `§` character.
(*serverUrl* and *externalMedia.data.image*).
I'm using this pattern :

```
/§.+§/g
```

but it catches also the characheters between the two groups.

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: `/§(.+?)§/g` or `/§(.*?)§/g` or `/§([^§]+)§/g` or `/§([^§]*)§/g` and use the `RegExp.exec()` in a loop to get all the substrings inside. See [*How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression).

Comment: How to exclude the '§' from the match?

Comment: See [*How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression), use `match[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make it lazy using `?` like this `§.+?§`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL0yE9/1)